# Comparing antlr generated tokens

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, dsl, antlr4

I have the following as part of my grammar (and here `'name'` and `'value'` are just static for simplicity, in practice they are not):

```
test4 : 'name' CMPOP 'value';

CMPOP       :   EQUALS | NOTEQUALS;
EQUALS      :   '=';
NOTEQUALS   :   '!=';
```

Now, what I want to do is handle different CMPOPs differently (possibly via a switch). Is there a way to get an int/enum version of the token underlying CMPOP (= or !=) while I am evaluating the expression in a FilterListener implementation? I know I can get the string with `getText()` but comparing strings everywhere can be slow. e.g. if I have `name=value` I can see that `=` TerminalNodeImpl and it has a Symbol. The only thing that looks similar there is the `type` property but that seems to give me CMPOP.

```
public void exitTest4(@NotNull testParser.Test4Context ctx) {
    System.out.println(ctx.CMPOP().getSymbol().toString());
    int type = ctx.CMPOP().getSymbol().getType();
    System.out.println(type + "," + testParser.tokenNames[type]);
}
```

Gives me:

```
[@1,4:4='=',<6>,1:4]
6,CMPOP
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
switch ( ctx.CMPOP().something() ) {
  EQUALS : //evaluate with = ; break
  NOTEQUALS : //evaluate with != ; break
}
```

Or am I going about this the wrong way? Should I move that to the parser rules rather than lexer rules to something like: `'name' (EQUALS | NOTEQUALS) 'value'` ?

I am using antlr4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two primary options. You can choose the method that works best for you.

#### Option 1: Change `CMPOP` to be a parser rule instead of a lexer rule

```
cmpOp
  : EQUALS
  | NOTEQUALS
  ;
```

*Advantages:*

- Easy to perform the change
- Easy to maintain the `cmpOp` rule if it ever needs to change
- Better conceptual grouping for `EQUALS` and `NOTEQUALS` as the comparison operators

#### Option 2: Remove the `CMPOP` rule, and inline the set in parser rules

Replace all code that currently references `CMPOP` with `(EQUALS | NOTEQUALS)` instead.

*Advantages:*

- 1 fewer parse tree nodes per comparison operator (minor reduction in memory overhead, if that matters for your case)

Comment: Do you think doing all that (switching to getType() rather than getText()) is a good idea in general or is it something that might break easily (e.g. across versions)? I wonder what the common way of doing this is.

Comment: You don't need to switch to `getType()`. Use `if (ctx.EQUALS() != null)` to check for `EQUALS` (the method `EQUALS()` is generated as part of the rule context class).

Comment: I think being able to do a switch becomes more important, especially as the number of possible values grows. Right now I have 6 for cmpOp but for some other tokens i have more than that.

Comment: If you change to option 1, still how do you get whether it's equals or not equals? There is no getType on a parser context.